# query result disappears between dao and service using spring mvc 4

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, resultset, missing-data

I've written a spring MVC web services app. I've driven the findall users path which results in a List of Users objects returned to the DAO but they don't make it to the calling method.

```
@Repository
@Scope("prototype")
public class UsersDao implements IUsersDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    /**
     * Retrieve all Users objects.
     * @return List of Users.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation =     Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
    public List<Users> findAll() {

        Query query = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().getNamedQuery(FIND_ALL);

        List<Users> users = (List<Users>)query.list();

        return users;
    }
```

At the return statement I have two Users objects - I have verified this in debug.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/users")
public class UserConfig {

    @Autowired
    IUsersDao dao;

   /**
    * Retrieves a List of all Users objects.
    * 
    * @return ArrayList of all Users
    */
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<Users> get() {

        List<Users> users = dao.findAll();

        if (users == null) {
            users = new ArrayList<Users>();
        }

        return users;
    }
```

By the time I get to if I have a null pointer. I know I've just done something silly but I can't stare at this any longer. Please help

I'm using the following dependencies:

```
<!-- Spring -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Here's the log:

```
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jul 28, 2014 7:34:23 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jul 28, 2014 7:34:23 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 5865 ms
Hibernate: select users0_.users_id as users_id1_5_, users0_.name as name2_5_, users0_.password as password3_5_, users0_.users_user_settings_id as users_us4_5_ from users users0_
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is FIND_ALL in your named query? It should be in double quotes "FIND_ALL".

Comment: @BillFromHawaii Try putting `@Transactional` at controller layer.

Comment: I don't think it was't even compiled successfully unless you have FIND_ALL constant on the page or you have did a static import.

Comment: FIND_ALL is in the DAO interface.

Comment: FIND_ALL is in the DAO interface:
 public static final String FIND_ALL = "Users.findAll";
Which refers to named queries in the model object:
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u"),

Comment: and I left out the dependency property as well: <org.springframework-version>4.0.3.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Aspect was intercepting the Controller method. Turned that off and everything worked like magic.

Thank you everyone for your helpful suggestions.